# Shuffle first 20 prepared statement results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an SQL query giving a result of about 100+ and I want to shuffle the first 20 results (the other 80+ should stay in the order as the SQL query selects them). Now the best method to do that (I don't want to increase the SQL load so no ORDER BY etc.) is to put the results in an array, slice the array, shuffle the sliced 20 results, put them back and display them. However, I'm not sure how to do that with an prepared statement. Any pointers?

```
$array = $stmt -> fetch();
```

Did not yield the results I hoped. That doesn't create an array with the results. Below you find the relevant part of the code:

```
$stmt->prepare($query);

  $stmt->bind_param('ssii', $dienstenpage, $huidigegemeente, $startpoint, $limit);

  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->bind_result($prepid, $prephoofdrubriek, $prepplaats, $prepbedrijfsnaam, $prepgemeente, $prepbedrijfsomschrijving, $prepbedrijfsslogan, $prepstraatnaam, $prephuisnummer, $preppostcode, $preptelefoonnummer, $prepfax, $prepemail, $prepwebsite, $prepbedrijfslogo, $prepdubb);


$stmt->store_result();

$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;


   while($stmt->fetch()) {

this displays all the results...

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to "shuffle" a table of database records?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610371/whats-the-best-way-to-shuffle-a-table-of-database-records)

Comment: @Qix, It is not, that question refers to shuffeling in the SQL query, I want to shuffle the result after the query has been executed.

Comment: You're correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fetchAll` to get an array with all the rows in. Then, do this:

```
$first20 = array_splice($allResults,0,20);
shuffle($first20);
array_splice($allResults,0,0,$first20);
```

This answer makes extensive use of [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/array-splice), quite a useful function!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you elaborate just a little more? How do I incorporate the fetchAll function? $array = $stmt->fetchAll(); doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I'm not certain what database library you're using, it's unfamiliar to me. You may need to just use the `while($stmt->fetch())` loop to build an array manually, but check the docs for your library first.

Comment: Hoping to avoid the latter, but I'll surely check out the docs, thanks so far!